# How to encapsulate code using JSP/taglibs/tiles

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, tiles, taglib

When I have come piece of HTML which is repeated over the JSP page, I can create a custom tag to encapsulate this peace.

But sometimes I need to repeat some code over and ove in every JSP page:

```
<header>
<sidebar>
<content>  <- this is the only one part that changes
<ad>
<footer>
```

As long as the variable part is inside the constant block, it's impossible to encapsulate it. What's the best way to avoid the duplication? I know there was TILES lib long time ago, but I think that in JavaEE6 there should be something more modern.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at something like [sitemesh](http://wiki.sitemesh.org/wiki/display/sitemesh/Home)? It built around the gang of four [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)